# PHP refactoring arrays based on same values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [insert_input_id] => 1
            [action_id] => 1
            [table] => users
            [name] => nickname
            [parent] => nickname
            [owner] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [insert_input_id] => 2
            [action_id] => 1
            [table] => users
            [name] => email
            [parent] => email
            [owner] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [insert_input_id] => 3
            [action_id] => 1
            [table] => users
            [name] => name
            [parent] => name
            [owner] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [insert_input_id] => 4
            [action_id] => 1
            [table] => users
            [name] => surname
            [parent] => surname
            [owner] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [insert_input_id] => 5
            [action_id] => 1
            [table] => social
            [name] => social_id
            [parent] => social_id
            [owner] => user_id
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [insert_input_id] => 6
            [action_id] => 1
            [table] => social
            [name] => social_token
            [parent] => social_token
            [owner] => user_id
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [insert_input_id] => 7
            [action_id] => 1
            [table] => social
            [name] => social_type
            [parent] => social_type
            [owner] => user_id
        )

)
```

As you may see from the above array, some have the same `[table]` value. In this specific case we have `[table] => social` and `[table] => users`. So I am trying to refactor the array based on the same tables and trying to achieve the following result.

```
Array
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [owner] => 
            [nickname] => giorgio
            [email] => giorgia@m.com
            [name] => giorgia
            [surname] => giorgio
        )

    [social] => Array
        (
            [owner] => user_id
            [social_id] => 23123
            [social_token] => 
            [social_type] => facebook
        )
```

)

This is what I am doing with my PHP code:

```
    foreach ($inserts as $insert) {
                if (isset($data[$insert['parent']])) {
                    $vals['owner'] = $insert['owner'];
                    $vals[$insert['name']] = $data[$insert['parent']];
                    $tables[$insert['table']] = $vals; 
}    
            }
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($tables); echo '</pre>';
```

`$data` is simply the data given by a `$_GET` or `$_POST` request.

Everything is fine regarding assigning the correct `$data`. The problem is that I am getting the following array:

```
Array
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [owner] => 
            [nickname] => giorgio
            [email] => giorgia@m.com
            [name] => giorgia
            [surname] => giorgio
        )

    [social] => Array
        (
            [owner] => user_id
            [nickname] => giorgio
            [email] => giorgia@m.com
            [name] => giorgia
            [surname] => giorgio
            [social_id] => 23123
            [social_token] => 
            [social_type] => facebook
        )

)
```

As you see the `[social]` array contains also the elements of the `[users]` array and this is wrong.

How can I avoid this?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is it wrong formatting or if should be surrounded by braces? in if (isset($data[$insert['parent']]))

Comment: @insanebits yes I forgot them. Thanks

Comment: You should edit your your post so it will be easier to understand how it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that inserts array inside foreach is same as data you get via GET/POST
Also if you need to join those array values by given table you can so something like this:

```
$refractored = array(); // refractored data
//insert has table key
foreach($inserts as $insert) 
{
    if(array_key_exist($insert["table"]))
    {
        $refractored[$insert["table"]] = array_merge($refractored[$insert["table"]], $insert);
    } else  {
        $refractored[$insert["table"]] = $insert;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the table in the $_GET/$_POST

Comment: So what type of array do you get ? And which one is first array in your question?(it has table field)..

Comment: The first array is what I get from the DB. The second array is the expected result. The third one is what I get from my code and it s wrong. The $_GET/$_POST array is not here and it's not usefull to resolve this issue. I need to understand a way to refactor the array based on the different tables and elements that belongs that that specific table

Comment: If I understand $inserts array is the one that you need to refractor and which is first in your example, it has that table value by which you can join your array. Sorry if don't understand your actual situation. I have edited my code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-initialize the $vals-array in each run of the loop. Otherwise its values and keys accumulate...

```
foreach ($inserts as $insert) {

        $vals = array();

        if (isset($data[$insert['parent']]))
                $vals['owner'] = $insert['owner'];
                $vals[$insert['name']] = $data[$insert['parent']];
                $tables[$insert['table']] = $vals;     
        }
```

Comment: doing this way will not give the expected result because the $vals array is empty each loop and does not even add the elements it should.

Comment: you're assigning the keys and values of `$vals` in the if-statement.

Comment: It is returning the following instead then the expected array: Array
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [owner] => 
            [surname] => giorgio
        )

    [social] => Array
        (
            [owner] => user_id
            [social_type] => facebook
        )

)